# Aggregate values into list like string and then cast to true list datatype

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["a", 1],
    ["a", 2],
    ["b", 5],
    ["b", 11]
])
df.columns=["c1","c2"]
grouped = df.groupby(["c1"])["c2"].apply(list)
grouped = grouped.reset_index()
grouped["c3"] = "[11,12]" #add list like string manually
#grouped["true_list_c2"] = grouped["c2"].apply(eval)
grouped["true_list_c3"] = grouped["c3"].apply(eval)
print(grouped)
```

If try to convert manually added column "c3" to true python list, it works.

But if try same for aggregated column "c2", raises error: `eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`

What is reason? what is difference between  "c2" and "c3" columns?

Comment: `c2` is a real list you can't eval rather than `c3` is a string you can eval and converted to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregated column "c2" is a series of lists, eval doesn't accept that. If you cast it to str `grouped["true_list_c2"] = grouped["c2"].apply(str).apply(eval)` (just like "c3") it works just fine.